# CMake: build library used by multiple projects

Tags: cmake

I have a directory containing several tools which I use for independent projects, e.g.:

```
CommonTools
  + Tool A
  + Tool B
  + Tool C
```

Tool B depends on Tool A, but Tool A can be used independently from Tool B. I think I have two options:

1. I can install the tools under a system directory (e.g. for Windows, `C:\Program Files`). This is not necessarily a good thing given that some of my programs are meant to be used in the same directory as the one they are shipped in because I don't have sufficient rights to write to a system directory). Besides, I still need to locate the header files to compile projects that use those tools.
2. I could use `find_library` to locate them. Then I run into the following problem: `find_library(A)` won't work until I've actually built A, so I can't `cmake CommonTools` (because Tool B requires Tool A). I could call cmake from make, but that looks rather convoluted...
3. I can put relative paths to Tool A in Tool B & only use `find_library` for other projects. Unfortunately, this relative path changes depending on whether I'm building CommonTools or Tool B.

What are your thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Are these tools all libraries which you can modify, and which use CMake themselves?

Comment: Yes they are. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Having driven my investigations a little further, I am now doing this: after each add_subdirectory command, I "register" the module by setting *manually* the module_FOUND, module_LIBRARIES & module_INCLUDE_DIRS variables but this seems a little clumsy to me. Inside Tool B, I have if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR ) find_package(Tool_A)... The idea is that if I'm building Tool B by itself, I want to check if it's available & perform an svn checkout if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

As I wanted to be able to perform one-step builds, this is what I ended up doing.

- I distinguish the submodules of the module I'm currently building from external dependencies & third-party tools. **Each (sub)module is only responsible for building itself**. This means that all external dependencies & third-party tools *must* be already installed or available in binary + header form from a server. As a corollary, it means that a missing dependency is a binary which should be available from a given server but isn't.
- Submodules are added using `add_subdirectory`, which means that if any of them is not available, the configuration step will fail with an explicit message.
- External dependencies & third-party tools are located using `find_package`. The `HINT` location is an option which must be provided by the user performing the build (this gives an indication of the module's dependencies to the user. If any of them is not found, a binary is downloaded from a given location using `ExternalProject_Add`. The `<module>_FOUND`, `<module>_LIBRARIES` & `<module>_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables must be set manually in the CMakeLists.txt file, but given a proper directory layout on the server side (e.g. `<module>-<version>-<platform>/include` & `<module>-<version>-<platform>/binaries`), it can be done in a consistent way (e.g. using a macro). There again, if no binaries are found on the server, the configuration step will fail with an explicit message.

All of this means that the continuous integration server will correctly detect any missing dependencies (i.e. components which should be on the server but aren't or submodules which are not under version control) at configuration time rather than at build time, while still allowing one-step builds.

I hope this can be of some use to others.

PS: as a side-node to Google Test users:  "gtest **must** be recompiled for each module because every user needs to compile his tests using the same compiler flags used to compile the installed Google Test libraries; otherwise he may run into undefined behaviors. If you compile Google Test and your test code using different compiler flags, they may see different definitions of the same class/function/variable)". This means you actually need (in my case) to run an `ExternalProject_Add` command in *every module* because each module contains its own tests.